# How to remove rows that contain 0 in data array of a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm currently working on a scipy sparse csr matrix. I would like to delete all rows in the matrix that contain 0 in the data array of the matrix (the data array is the 1s and 2s you can see in the example below). So far I have the following

```
indexRowsToBeDeleted = []
for rowIndex, dataValue in enumerate(someSparseCsrMatrix.data):
    if dataValue == 0:
        indexRowsToBeDeleted.append(rowIndex)
```

Here's what the matrix looks like (it's basically created by using the CountVectorizer from sklearn):

```
(0, 1735)   1
(0, 2988)   1
(0, 3366)   2
(0, 3850)   2
(0, 5424)   1
(0, 6537)   1
(0, 7653)   1
:   :
(6383, 15600)   1
(6383, 18689)   1
(6383, 19008)   1
(6383, 19012)   1
(6383, 20094)   1
(6383, 20368)   1
```

Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: can you give an example  of how your matrix looks like ?

Comment: Sure. I've just added an example.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to delete `0`'s out of the `data` field of a sparse matrix?

Comment: I'm working on feature regularization (corruption) for sentiment classification. Although I'm not sure if it matters to delete features with a frequency of 0 in the feature vectors (I changed  frequency counts to 0 for some features depending on their feature weights instead of removing the features since I couldn't figure out how to remove them from the matrix at that point...

Comment: Do you want to remove all 0's, leaving the matrix the same shape?  Or reduce the number of rows as well?

Comment: I wanted to reduce the number of rows as well

Answer (score 0):

With CSR format, it's trivial: just call [`eliminate_zeros()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros) on the matrix!